# Как сделать предзагрузку actions.sks в spriteKit?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, spritekit

Пишу игру на spriteKit. В actions.sks храниться анимация. При тесте на реальном аппарате приложение вылетает при попытке обратиться к анимации. В симуляторе все работает нормально. Видимо, не успевает загрузиться actions.sks. Как сделать предзагрузку? Как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Вы уверены что проблема в этом? Может ресурсы не копируются на устройство? Проверьте в Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

Comment: Нет, не уверен. Ресурсы копируются. Судя по всему проблема в оперативке. Приложение отваливается на отсечке 685МБ. Тестирую на iPad 3. Там 1 Гб. Как бороться с нехваткой памяти? Понятно, что надо оптимизировать анимацию. Судя по всему именно она съедает много, но приложение не должно же просто вываливаться